# What does "rebound chick" mean?

Tags: meaning

It's the name of this great kizomba song by Nelson Freitas.

http://youtu.be/eyCxsHPN1gs

What does exactly the "rebound chick" mean?

Comment: I don't need to watch this video to answer your question. A *rebound* (note: male or female) is a person whom one dates after breaking up with another partner in order to forget about or *get over* the previous relationship. *Rebound flings* are usually shallow and not meant to last. The goal is for one to *move on.* The only thing I'm unsure of is to whether to refer to this as colloquial, slang, or just idiomatic. I'd say one of the first two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Rebound chick" means a girl who'll help you recover your self-esteem after a breakup. Not a permanent solution because you didn't fall in love with her; you were looking for a friend; and she'll always see you as wounded. Always warn someone you meet if you're "on the rebound" and not really able to give love.

Comment: One could also throw the word "desperation" into this explanation somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

She's like a temporary girlfriend after the end of a long-term relationship with a girl you loved, this term mainly used to describe the occurrence sexual encounter in order to forget the past relationship.
Example:Tom was with Shelly for 5 years. He was with Suzy for 5 days. Suzy was his rebound chick.